# Project Euler p14, stackoverflowerror java (in bluej)

Tags: java, bluej

I'm working on euler problem 14 (http://projecteuler.net/problem=14). I've tried to tackle it by having a method which runs through the collatz equations, and returns the number of steps taken. If it's higher then the current record it overwrites it, otherwise it moves on to the next integer. It was giving stack overflow errors so I added the system.out.println messages to try and identify where it was stalling, and currently it dies whenever it reaches 5200~, I'm confused as to why, because as far as i can tell no values encountered at this point should go over the int limit, and the error persisted even if i changed "numberStorage" from int to long.

Here is my current code:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class calculator here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class Calculator
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;
    private int startingNumber = 1;
    private int stepCount;
    private int numberStorage;
    private int currentRecordStart;
    private int currentRecordSteps = 0;
    /**
     * a string and int value to track multiple starting numbers with the same number of steps
     */
    private String tieNote = "no ties";
    private int multiTie = 0;


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class calculator
     */
    public Calculator()
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    /**
     * begins function
     */

    public void initiater()
    {
        numberStorage = 0;
        stepCount = 0;
        startingNumber = 1;
        currentRecordStart = 1;
        currentRecordSteps = 0;
        stepCount = 0;
        recordHolder(1,1);

    }

    /**
     * starts next rotation
     */

    public void steprunner()
    {
        ++startingNumber;
        System.out.println("starting rotation " + startingNumber + " current record " + currentRecordSteps);
        stepCount = 0;
        numberStorage = 0;
        recordHolder(startingNumber, collatzSequence(startingNumber));
    }

    /**
     * Runs collatz sequence and updates a variable with the number of steps.
     */
    public int collatzSequence(int N)
    {
        numberStorage = 0;
        numberStorage = N;

         if (N == 1)
         {
             return stepCount;
            }
         else if ( (N & 1) == 0)
         {
            numberStorage = numberStorage / 2;
            ++stepCount;
            return collatzSequence(numberStorage);

          }
          else if ( (N & 1) != 0)
          {
               numberStorage = 3 * numberStorage + 1;
               ++stepCount;
               numberStorage = numberStorage / 2;
               ++stepCount;
               return collatzSequence(numberStorage);

          }

        return stepCount;


    }

    /**
     * stores record and starts next cycle
     */
    public void recordHolder(int startingnumber, int stepcount)
     {
           if (startingNumber <= 999999)
          {
             if (stepcount > currentRecordSteps)
             {
                 currentRecordSteps = stepcount;
                 currentRecordStart = startingnumber;
                 tieNote = "no ties";
                 multiTie = 0;
                 System.out.println("a tie occured!");
                }
                else if (stepcount == currentRecordSteps)
                {
                    tieNote = ("starting number " + startingnumber + " also had " + stepcount + "steps");
                    ++multiTie;
                    System.out.println("a secondary tie occured!");
                }
             steprunner();
          }
          if (startingNumber == 999999)
          {
              simulationEnder();
            }

     }

    /**
     * ends simulation
     */
     public void simulationEnder()
     {
        System.out.println("the number with the highest number of steps was " + currentRecordStart + 
        " with " + currentRecordSteps + " steps!");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to read your code. But I can show you a solution, written in pseudocode, that is simple and quick:

```
function euler14(n):
  cs := makeArray(1..n)
  maxX, maxLen, cs[1] := 1, 1, 1
  for k from 2 to n
    c, s := 0, k
    while k <= s
      if s % 2 == 0
        s := s / 2
      else
        s := 3 * s + 1
      c := c + 1
    cs[k] := cs[s] + c
    if maxLen < xs[k]
      maxX, maxLen := k, cs[k]
  return maxX
```

The trick is to calculate and save the values of the lengths of the collatz chain, in order starting from 1; then, if a future sequence drops below its starting point, calculation stops in favor of a simple lookup. Here the `cs` array is the cache, `k` is the index of the chain that is currently being computed, `s` is the current item in the chain, and `c` is the current length of the chain. Computing `euler14(1000000)` should take no more than a second or two.

Comment: Oh, smart. Hadn't thought of that :p

I redid my own code but used an arraylist to store values, and referenced back to them whenever the N fell below the current starting value and now it works. I guess it was just looping too many function or something.

Thanks for you're help! :)